# How can I export my Ubuntu terminal's color scheme for use on other computers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, terminal, color-profiles

How can I export my Ubuntu terminal's color scheme for use on other computers?

I've set up a color scheme that I like and I'd like to put it in a git repo for easy loading from other machines. Any strategy that would make it work in other terminal apps too, such as Konsole?

Comment: SCM for terminal color profiles? I would never have thought! You can also use Ubuntu One, or Dropbox, to share file between PC's and friends.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the system with the colors and settings you want, run:

```
gconftool-2 --dump '/apps/gnome-terminal' > gnome-terminal-conf.xml
```

then `gnome-terminal-conf.xml` to your `git` repo.

Then on the other machines, run

```
gconftool-2 --load gnome-terminal-conf.xml
```

to set it.

If you're not sure how to use `git`, see the [git tutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html), and [github.com](http://github.com) for a popular git hosting service.

Note that this method overwrites **all** settings.  Try running

```
gconftool-2 -R '/apps/gnome-terminal'
```

to see all the settings that will be affected.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. [Please check my question](http://askubuntu.com/q/668227/148451) and see if you have any solution. Thank you!